# Sequence alignment for hierarchical cluster analysis on categorical sequence data

Tags: r, sequence, hierarchical-clustering, sequence-analysis

I have a dataset of short-term behaviors displayed by 30 individuals.

```
#Load packages
library(TraMineR)

# Function to generate a random non-numerical sequence
generate_random_sequence <- function(length) {
  alphabet <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K")  
  return(sample(alphabet, length, replace = TRUE))
}

# Generate 15 sequences with lengths between 15 and 40
num_sequences <- 30
min_length <- 15
max_length <- 40

# Create a data frame
sequence_data <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol = max_length, nrow = num_sequences))

# Populate the data frame with random sequences
for (i in 1:num_sequences) {
  seq_length <- sample(min_length:max_length, 1)
  sequence_data[i, 1:seq_length] <- generate_random_sequence(seq_length)
}

# Create the sequence object using seqdef
sequences <- seqdef(sequence_data, informat = "STS")
```

I want to perform hierarchical cluster analysis to see if a continuous variable `x` predicts which cluster each sequence falls into.
However my sequences are wildly different lengths. I have tried running dynamic time warping but my understanding is that, due to the fact that DTW uses distances, it cannot be applied to categorical data. I'm at a loss - how can align my sequences so that I can perform the HCA?

Answer (score 0):

Clustering categorical sequences is typical sequence analysis (SA)  (See the wikipedia page [Sequence analysis in social sciences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_analysis_in_social_sciences) and the many references given there).

There exist multiple ways of measuring dissimilarities between categorical sequences, including between sequences of different length. See the review by [Studer & Ritschard (2016)](https://doi.org/10.1111/rssa.12125). Many of them can be computed with the `seqdist` function of the TraMineR package.

I illustrate below using the optimal matching distance with INDELSLOG indel and substitution costs (costs based on the frequency of occurrences of the different tokens)

```
dist.om <- seqdist(sequences, method="OM", sm="INDELSLOG")
hcl <- hclust(as.dist(dist.om))
plot(hcl)
```

[image]